# Como adicionar/remover itens dentro do Carrinho

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de fazer um Carrinho simples, onde utilizei como base algumas explicações aqui dentro do Stack mesmo. Segue abaixo meu Controller do Carrinho:

```
public class CarrinhoController : Controller
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    public ActionResult AdicionarCarrinho(int id)
    {

        Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

        var produto = db.Produtos.Find(id);

        if (produto != null)
        {
            var itemPedido = new ItemPedido();
            itemPedido.ItemPedidoID = Guid.NewGuid();
            itemPedido.Produto = produto;
            itemPedido.Qtd = 1;

            if (carrinho.ItensPedido.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProdutoID == produto.ProdutoID) != null)
            {
                carrinho.ItensPedido.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProdutoID == produto.ProdutoID).Qtd += 1;
            }

            else
            {
                carrinho.ItensPedido.Add(itemPedido);
            }
            carrinho.ValorTotal = carrinho.ItensPedido.Select(i => i.Produto).Sum(d => d.Valor);

            Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
    }

    public ActionResult Carrinho()
    {
        Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

        return View(carrinho);
    }

    public ActionResult ExcluirItem(Guid id)
    {
        var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();
        var itemExclusao = carrinho.ItensPedido.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemPedidoID == id);
        carrinho.ItensPedido.Remove(itemExclusao);

        Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
        return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
    }

    public ActionResult SalvarCarrinho()
    {
        var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

        db.Pedidos.Add(carrinho);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
    }
}
```

Abaixo seguem as minhas classes sendo usadas:

```
public class ItemPedido
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ItemPedidoID { get; set; }

    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

    public int PedidoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }

    public int Qtd { get; set; }


}
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Produto")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do produto deve ter entre 5 a 20 caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a descrição do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Descrição")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do produto deve ter entre 5 a 50 caracteres")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o valor do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Valor R$")]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    //relacionamentos
    public int RestauranteID { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurante Restaurante { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemPedido> ItensPedido { get; set; }
}

public class Pedido
{
    public int PedidoID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DtPedido { get; set; }

    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public Decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public Decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemPedido> ItensPedido { get; set; }
}
```

Abaixo está a única View que eu fiz, baseado nas explicações anteriores:

```
 @model FoodInTime.Models.Pedido
 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "Carrinho";
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutCliente.cshtml";
}

<h2>Carrinho</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model.ItensPedido)
{
<li>
    @item.ProdutoID - @item.Produto.Nome

    <input type="text" value="@item.Qtd" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="submit" value="alterar" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Remover", "ExcluirItem", new { id = item.ProdutoID }, null)
</li>
}

@Html.ActionLink("Retornar", "Cardapio", "Restaurantes")
```

O que eu quero, é saber onde eu clico pra adicionar um Produto que está no meu Cardápio e ele entrar nessa View de Carrinho. Ou seria uma View que adiciona os itens no Carrinho, por ser uma Action? 
Desculpem a ignorância, eu realmente não sou bom com programação.
Meu Cardápio é uma List de Produtos.

Answer (score 1):

No seu cardápio você deverá criar um link, ou fazer um post para

> "~/Carrinho/AdicionarCarrinho/@idProduto".

De acordo com o seu código, isso irá adicionar o item no carrinho (caso não exista) ou aumentar a quantidade deste item no carrinho (caso já exista) e depois irá redirecionar o usuário para a página do carrinho.